# Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence and $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n+p}=x_n$. Then $(x_n)$ is constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence and $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n: x_{n+p}=x_n$.

Assume that $(x_{n})$ converges, then $(x_n)$ is constant.

How can I prove this statement. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Assume it is not constant. Then it oscillates.

Comment: Where does your sequence live? For example, your statement is wrong, if the space in question is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @martini One of the tags is real analysis, so maybe that's enough to assume we are in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence weren't constant, there would exist $k,k'\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_k\neq x_{k'}$. Define two constant subsequences $(x_{k+np})_n$ and $(x_{k'+np})_n$ which obviously converge to different limits. This is contradiction with assumption that $(x_n)$ is convergent.